# want to show number one by one after a second through interval

Tags: javascript

i want to show numbers one by one after a second, but below coding shows the whole numbers together.

```
function showVal(){
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        var showingVal= document.write("the number is "+i);
        document.write("<br />");       
    }
}
setInterval('showVal()',1000);
```

Comment: Well, your logic is flawed. You are calling `showVal` once every second, and in each call you are iterating from `0` to `4` writing out the number. You should only write one number in the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use `setTimeout` instead.

```
function showVal(n) {
  if(!n)
    n = 0;
  var showingVal = document.write("the number is " + n);
  document.write("<br />");       

  if(n < 4) {
    setTimeout(function() { showVal(n + 1); }, 1000);
  }
}

setTimeout(showVal, 1000);
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/avunif

It's better than `setInterval` because after you printed 5 numbers, your tick handler won't be called. Efficiency. Plus no global variables. :-)

Or you can `clearInterval` instead.

Comment: You can't use `document.write` once the page is complete. I have tried the demo in Firefox and IE, and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Guffa: well, in Chrome it works. But it's irrelevant. One can build up an `innerHTML` or log to console, depending on what's the purpose of this logic.

Answer (score 1):

don't use the loop inside function, instead use a global variable and use it inside the function and check if the number reached the limit then clear your interval

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `document.write` in an interval, as that will write to the document after it is completed, and then the document will be replaced by the text instead.

Also, the code in the function doesn't output one number at a time, it outputs all numbers at once. You need a counter outside the function so that it can keep track of where it is.

Use `clearInterval` to stop the interval once it has output all the numbers.

Put the text inside an element that already exists in the page. Place the code below the element in the page, so that the element is created when the code starts.

```
<div id="SomeElement"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var handle, counter = 0, text = '';

function showVal(){
  if (counter < 5) {
    text += "the number is " + counter + "<br />";       
    document.getElementById("SomeElement").innerHTML = text;
    counter++;
  } else {
    window.clearInterval(handle);
  }
}

handle = window.setInterval(showVal, 1000);

</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/CY5DV/

(This can be done in a closure so that it doesn't pollute the global scope with the variables, but that's not important for the main issues in this question.)

Answer (score 0):

```
function printCount() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
       setTimeout(function() {
            document.write(i + "<br>");
            }, i * 1000);
        }
   }
   printCount();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation